# PHP download corrupted/empty

Tags: php, download

My code uploads a file, inserts a unique key into a SQL database and then returns a download link. I read that i should use mysqli instead of mysql so i changed that and thought i was all set, 1-2 weeks passed without any coding and now when i try to open the downloaded file they are corrupted or empty.

A .txt containing "test" returned this code http://pastebin.com/NPiw0bve. 
I then noticed i still had some mysql extensions so i quickly changed that to mysqli and now this error disappears and all .txt files are instead empty.

Since the upload is correct, and it adds keys to the database why would it complain about

```
database problem Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Your link to your database is broken.
Access denied fpr user '' means, u pass no username to the database connection. Make sure your connection is estabilished and ready.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user[,$pass[,$db]]);
```

then check if $connection is a ressource and a valid sql link. if its not valid, most mysqli-functions return false or "" (nothing - empty string) and thats why your download is empty.

mysqli-functions are not the the same as mysql, check the manual for all your needs and edit your code.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but my connection is fine? I have specified host,user,pass and put them in mysqli_connect() and from there on mysqli_select_db. It connects and insert a unique key just fine, which means it is after that something goes wrong. Or am i wrong on this one?

Comment: if so, then why use of mysqli_select_db when select db inside the connect func? anyways, are there spelling errors in your query func? like $conn, $con or something else? your descriptions looks like u dont pass a user or had u simply removed for this question?

Comment: I now removed select_db, thanks for that. And no, there are no spelling errors. Here is the code (I already have user,pass etc set): http://pastebin.com/2rHkgc1k -- Got something to do with headers? That worked before i changed to mysqli_

Comment: that codes looks good. i would try to check what `$conn` holds, so that script bellow wouldn't run if `$conn!==false` - the error u get at line 29 (pastebin) fires cause no password and user is given OR the mysqli cant connect to an older mysql server. i dont think that this is a header problem, u can simply remove the `headers()` and checks what that script puts out on browser, if that is fine it should download with `headers()` added

Answer (score 0):

Changing from mysql to mysqli is not not only a change in adding a **i** to mysql. There is a little bit change in procedure too.

Better refer this link which can be useful for beginners in mysqli [Beginners mysqli tutorial](http://codular.com/php-mysqli).

The tutorial is in Oops style and if u are following procedural style not much use of this tutorial. But definetly u will get some ideas about mysqli.

An eg in Procedural coding style:

**sample code used in mysql connection**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
// we use seperate line for mysql connection and db selection. 
?>
```

and the queries will be like `mysql_query("select * from tablename");`

**sample code used in mysqli connection**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// We use single line for db selection and mysql connection.
?>
```

and the queries will be like `mysqli_query($conn, "select * from tablename");`
here we maintain connection in all queries using **$conn**

**Note:** This is not a solution for ur upload error. since u didn't shown ur codesin proper manner I assume maybe these changes causing error in ur code.